# ZIO: Why I get 'An unchecked error was produced.'

Tags: scala, zio

I have a misunderstanding with exception handling in *ZIO*. I followed the [ZIO-Documentation](https://zio.dev/docs/overview/overview_handling_errors#folding).

In a test class I run the following code:

```
  new DefaultRuntime {}.unsafeRun(
    (for {
      peopleRef <- Ref.make(Vector(People()))
      _ <- people(2).provide(Test(peopleRef)) // this throws the exception
    } yield ())
      .fold(
        err =>
          err shouldBe ServiceException("No People with id 2"), 
        _ => fail("line above should fail")
      )
  )
```

I thought with the `fold` function I could handle this exception, but it does not even get there. I get this Exception on the console:

```
Fiber failed.
An unchecked error was produced.
pme123.zio.examples.swapi.package$ServiceException
    at pme123.zio.examples.swapi.Swapi$Test$$anon$4.$anonfun$people$6(Swapi.scala:57)
    at zio.ZIO$MapFn.apply(ZIO.scala:2590)
    at zio.ZIO$MapFn.apply(ZIO.scala:2588)
    at zio.internal.FiberContext.evaluateNow(FiberContext.scala:709)
    at zio.Runtime.unsafeRunAsync(Runtime.scala:93)
    ....
```

What do I miss?

Here is a minimal example:

```
object MyApp
  extends App {

  def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[Environment, Nothing, Int] =
    program
      .fold({ error => 1 // this is not reached
      }, _ => 0)

  private lazy val program = for {
    peopleRef <- Ref.make(Vector(22))
    _ <- Test(peopleRef).people(12)
  } yield ()

  case class Test(ref: Ref[Vector[Int]]) {

    def people(id: Int): Task[Int] =
      for {
        ints <- ref.get
      } yield ints.find(_ == id) match {
        case None => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"No People with id $id") // this is thrown
        case Some(p) =>  p
      }
  }
}
```

Here is the whole code: [SwapiTest.scala](https://github.com/pme123/zio-examples/blob/master/entity/test/src/pme123/zio/examples/SwapiTest.scala)

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] of your problem?

Comment: you need to provide `people` method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I added the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZIO doesn't catch exception unless you wrap it in `ZIO`. You can use `ZIO.effect` to wrap the  entire block of legacy unsafe code throwing exceptions or just use `IO.fail` for specific exception.

I refactored your code to be more ZIO-like and produce failed `Task` instead of throwing exception:

```
case class Test(ref: Ref[Vector[Int]]) {

  def people(id: Int):Task[Int]=
    for {
      ints <- ref.get
      int  <- ZIO.effectTotal(ints.find(_ == id))
      res  <- int match {
        case None => IO.fail(new IllegalArgumentException(s"No People with id $id"))
        case Some(p) =>  ZIO.effectTotal(p)
      }
    }  yield res

}
```

In order to catch `IllegalArgumentException` you need the following fold:

```
...

.fold(
    err => err shouldBe IllegalArgumentException("No People with id 2"), 
    _   => fail("line above should fail")
 )
```

`ServiceException` should not appear here as nothing throwing it.

Comment: thanks, so in essence, the exception must be wrapped in a `IO.fail` and put into the `for-comprehension`